# Page jumping with <page maintainScrollPosition="true"></page>

Tags: asp.net, forms

I am in the process of developing a website using ASP.NET v4.0.30319 in visual web developer.  After spending countless hours attempting to get the `maintainScrollPosition` to work ANYWHERE I would love if anyone could shed some light on the situation.

I have attempted to place `<@... maintainScrollPosition="true" >` in the first line of my page declaration.  I have attempted `Page.maintainScrollPostion="true"` on the page (though I'm not quite sure where I should put it).  I have also attempted to create a `<pages>` section in the web.config file (though that returned error from my browser when viewing).

I have been trying these in all places I can, but if I am able to compile successfully it just doesn't work, the page still jumps to top.

I have seen people posting about the option of using JScript as follows:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     window.scrollTo = function( x,y ) 
     {
         return true;
     }
 </script>
```

though I am not quite sure where to place this in my file.  I am new to ASP.NET environment, but am comfortable in visual C#.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would love you forever.  This has been such a headache for my partner and I.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx#1

Comment: Which browser(s) have you tested?  It doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: Also, what did you put in your web.config?  (see http://www.aspxtutorial.com/post/2011/06/28/Maintain-scroll-position-after-Postback-is-fired-in-aspnet-page.aspx)  If you used that code in your config and it blew up then I'd suspect it's not a 4.0 site.

Comment: Good point, it's not a 'standard' browser function. As are many things that Microsoft introduce. IE supports it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick replies. We were testing that in Firefox 5, makes a lot of sense if it is supported in only some browsers.

In the web.config file i had read to put in:
<page maintainScrollPosition="true"></page>

Comment: so after trying this in IE everything works as it should.  Is there any chance you know how to implement something like this which would work across browsers??  Thanks again.  Peter